# System went read only...won't allow me to boot

Tags: live-cd, drive, read-only

I accidentally made my system read only. After a quick Google search I know this can be fixed by remounting the drive using sudo mount "        ".

The problem is I already restarted my system thinking that would be some sort of noob fix... I am currently on a live CD since my laptop wont boot at all. The problem is the live CD does not see my laptops hard drive. How can I mount whats not their... I tried gparted but the program does not see a built in hard drive. If I trying reinstalling Ubuntu (which is not a problem since I back up everything) it says I have no hard drive?!

If it helps I am on a Toshiba and I have what Ubuntu recommends for partitions when you don't customize them on install.

Comment: I tried just now to use a fedora live CD for S&Giggles with no luck. The fedora CD says "can not install Fedora due to no write read/write access on disk"

Comment: try to install windows if it says the same problem again i think may be the HDD fault.

Comment: ok, do that now.

Comment: Is there no way to fix this inside of linux?

Comment: I just checked using windows. it does not list a disc.

Comment: I am confused. I was on my computer when it happend. you say the hard drive is dead?! I only had the problem after restarting...

Comment: I think HDD has the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If gparted doesn't see your hard drive, it's likely it's dead.  Sorry.  Either that or unplugged. :D